# MySQL substring performance

Tags: sql, mysql

Does anybody know what the performance of using substring in MySQL is like? I have some insert and update calls where I have to truncate all the fields (up to around 15) using substring statements. These will get call pretty regularly so I'm a little worried about performance.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about what you're doing?  I'm interested to know why you're planning on repeatedly truncating text

Comment: If you have to trim text, becuase it's part of some ETL process say, then you have to trim text, whether or not it performs badly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intensive string handling in SQL generally performs relatively poorly (it's not what SQL was designed for).

But you should first profile to make sure you actually have a bottleneck.

[If you were using MS SQL Server, then any complex string handling (like regular expression matching) should probably use a CLR stored procedure.]

Comment: @Mitch - I took the liberty of removing a couple of superfluous `T`'s left behind!

Comment: yeah sorry I was pretty implicit with it being in my tag only

Comment: @Martin Smith: TSQL is a standard, isn't it? but if it's not thanks! :)

Comment: do you have a reference or an explanation for why SQL performs poorly at intensive string handling?

Comment: @stevebot: it's from experience. But you can quickly write some small tests to verify...